# Determine the finite stable subsets of $(\mathbb{Z}, \cdot)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

I have to find all the finite stable subsets of $(\mathbb{Z}, \cdot)$. I know that a subset $M$ is a stable subset of $(\mathbb{Z}, \cdot)$ iff $\forall$ $x, y \in M$ we have $x \cdot y \in M$.

Intuitively, I though that the only integers that might be "capable of stability" are $A = \{-1,0, 1\}$. So then I quickly checked all of $A$'s subsets and reached the conclusion that the finite stable subsets of $(\mathbb{Z}, \cdot)$ are the following:

$$\bigg\{ \{ 0 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 0, 1 \}, \{ -1, 1 \}, \{ -1, 0, 1 \} \bigg\}$$

Is my solution correct? Did I miss something? Or did I get the problem's statement completely wrong?

Comment: That looks right.  If $\vert n \vert \geq 2, n \in M$ then $ \{ n^k \mid k \in \Bbb N \} \subseteq M$ and is infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. It shouldn't be hard to check that these sets all work, so all that should be left is to justify your intuition that nothing besides $-1$, $0$, and $1$ are capable of stability.

To do this rigorously, we want to start with a subset $M$ that is stable, and show it can't contain some $n$ not in $\{-1,0,1\}$. Say it does contain some $n$. The "capable of stability" condition is essentially the property that $M$ must have finitely many elements, so you want to find infinitely many elements in $M$ that you can generate from a single $n\not\in\{-1,0,1\}$.

All you know at the beginning is that $n\in M$, and you want to find more elements. Since $M$ is closed under multiplication, you can start multiplying elements of $M$ together; the only product you can make from the start is $n\cdot n=n^2$, but now $\{n,n^2\}\subset M$, and you can find more numbers that are supposed to be in $M$. In particular, $n\cdot n^2=n^3\in M$, ...